# Can't connect to server on SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

When I open the Management Studio and try to connect using the [PCNAME]/SQLEXPRESS it shows this error:

> "Cannot connect to [PCNAME]\SQLEXPRESS"

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error Message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection     to SQL Server. The server was not found
>   or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476"

I've also tried "localhost", "local" and "." in the place for [PCNAME] but to no avail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure SQL Server (SQL Express) service is running.

in powershell prompt type:

```
Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'
```

service "status" property should be reported as "Running"

If it is not, type (you need to be in elevated prompt, i.e. "Run as Administrator"):

Start-Service -Name 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'

OR

click start > type cmd and type

```
sc query MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

State should be reported as "Running"

If it is not, type (you need to be in elevated prompt, i.e. "Run as Administrator"):

```
sc start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

If you get an error that the service cannot be found:
Open SQL server Configuration Manager and make sure you have SQL server express installed:
[image]

Comment: How do I do that? I'm really a rookie at these things. Your name looks Serbian or Macedonian haha

Comment: I tried the one in cmd but it says "The specified service does not exist as an installed service." Done as administrator :S

Comment: You are trying to connect to the default sql express instance. Are you sure you have one installed?

Comment: I installed SQL Management Studio 2008 the same way as I have installed it before. I don't understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Well s**t. There's nothing there. Is it a necessity for the computer to be restarted after installation or have I messed up somewhere else?

Comment: You can try restarting the computer but I don't think that it is going to work. Please update your question with more detail on what have you installed, how and on what OS. Thanks

Comment: Ahhh.. Well I installed it on another computer through Team Viewer and I don't have any more time to perform changes or reinstall. I guess I'll have to update tomorrow..

Comment: Installing Management Studio != Installing SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

open you sqlserver config manager enable your tcpip both sqlserver and express and also under client protocol anf try to turnoff your firewall this will allow remote connection

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this applies to SQL Server Express

Answer (score 0):

first check sql server is running or not if not start it from services.msc
then
add .\SQLEXPRESS it will resolve problem